# Handling Android M run-time permissions with multi module project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I have a multiple module Android M app. Several modules require "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" & "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permissions.

I would like to ask the user  for permissions once:
    1. Where would be the right place to do that?
       1.1 Are permissions granted per activity?
       1.2 Would asking for permission in module 1 give permissions to all app?
       1.3 Is there a way to ask for both READ & WRITE permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has published guidelines describing when to ask for permissions. It depends on context. Your questions 1.1 and 1.2 can be answered with the same info: permissions are granted and denied at the app level. It applies to every part of your app package. For 1.3: they are limited together into a group. When you ask for one you automatically get everything in the group.

This talk from DroidconNYC NYC will give you more details: https://youtu.be/WGz-alwVh8A.

Answer (score 1):

> Where would be the right place to do that?

From somewhere in your UI, before you need those permissions.

> Are permissions granted per activity?

No, they are for the entire application.

> Would asking for permission in module 1 give permissions to all app?

Asking for a permission in a module will give that permission to the entire app, if the user grants you the permission.

> Is there a way to ask for both READ & WRITE permissions?

In this case, AFAIK you do not need both. Just ask for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. In general, you can request as many permissions as you want; the `requestPermissions()` method takes a `String[]` of permission names.